# Android save an image url as a resource

Tags: android, download

I have a very simple question:
I want to be able to save an image from a URL as a resource (temporarily, so it is deleted when the application closes), so I can then use it as an image resource (for example by setImageResource(int resID));

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use image as resource if its wasn't compiled into your application. The only imaginable way would be to modify the .apk file installed on the device, and that is not possible.

But I think what you're really asking: how can I set downloaded image to `ImageView` (or similar) so it can be displayed.

Your steps:

1. Download image to file on sdcard (Use [`HTTPClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) or [`URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)).
2. Use [`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(File)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) to load `Bitmap` from file into memory. You can safely delete the file after this step. It's no longer needed (unless you plan to re-use it later, of course).
3. Use [`ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) to set just loaded `Bitmap` object to `ImageView`.

And don't forget to call [`Bitmap.recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) when loaded `Bitmap` object is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to save an image as a resource and then reference it by ID.
When you application is compiled the R class is genereated, where the resources are referenced. You can read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

What I would do in your case is to download the image to internal/external storage then load it from the storage when needed. I would then delete the image when you finish your activity.